# Mongo Preventing access to dangerous command

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongosh

Reading [Mongo: Definite guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-the-definitive/9781491954454/):

In first chapter, author mentions the following snippet to change some of the default commands of `db`:

```js
var no = function() {
   print("Not on my watch.");
};

// Prevent dropping databases
db.dropDatabase = DB.prototype.dropDatabase = no;

// Prevent dropping collections
DBCollection.prototype.drop = no;

// Prevent dropping an index
DBCollection.prototype.dropIndex = no;

// Prevent dropping indexes
DBCollection.prototype.dropIndexes = no;
```

I know `db` is pointing to current database, but my question is from where does `DB` is coming from?